# How does the behavior of .Take() changes based on the interface reference I'm using on left. IQueryable vs IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, iqueryable

Assume I've these sample codes

```
IQueryable<Employee> data = context.Employees.Where(x => x.FullName != "Shekar Reddy");                    
    var topEmp = data.Take(1);
      foreach (var item in topEmp)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(item.FullName);
       }
```

and

```
IEnumerable<Employee> data = context.Employees.Where(x => x.FullName != "Shekar Reddy");                    
   var topEmp = data.Take(1);
   foreach (var item in topEmp)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(item.FullName);
      }
```

the only difference between these to is the the reference I'm using IQueryable vs IEnumerable.
1st snippet is generating sql query to get top 1 item matching the filter criteria and the later is generating a sql query without top filter.

In both the cases, the object inside the **data** is of type
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable
however the topEmp in the first scenaro is of type : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable
and
in second it is System.Linq.Enumerable.EnumerablePartition

How the behavior of the .Take method changes based on the interface reference on the left. I see the "data" varialbe is of same type in both cases. As per my understanding, if the left side reference is a class then .Take of that class could get called; but they are interfaces. I'm sure I'm missing a basic concept of C# here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you've missed a basic concept of C#, and this concept is **extension methods**.

We are not calling an abstract `Take` method implemented by the `Enumerable` object.

Instead, we are invoking a function that exists separately to the object: the `Take` extension methods. There are different methods based upon the type of object.

Inside the System.Core library exist these static classes.

```
public static class Queryable 
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> Take<TSource>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
        int count
    ); 
    // Many other methods...
}


public static class Enumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Take<TSource>(
       this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
       int count
     );
     // Many other methods...
}
```

Extension methods are resolved at compile time, not runtime.

Your `data` variable happens to implement `IQueryable<T>`. But, once you've cast it to an `IEnumerable<T>`, the compiler must choose the `IEnumerable<T>` extension method.

Comment: Yeah.... Now it is all clear to me. It didn't occur to me that we can have Extension methods on interfaces IEnumerable<TSource> and IQueryable<TSource>. I was only thinking in terms of interface implementation and wondering how this all was happening at runtime. Didn't even think about this compile time scenario. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the same `.Take()` methods.

`Enumerable.Take` returns a new `IEnumerable` that will enumerate items in the enumeration and yield them.

`Queryable.Take` returns a new `IQueryable`, to represent an `Expression` tree. When you start enumerating that queryable, the expression will be compiled into SQL.